# Event listener on an image doesn't alter the display state of an unordered list

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When the user clicks the menu bar `<img>` on the top right of the page, the `<ul>` display property should be changed from `none` to `display: block` and vice versa. I have global variables for the image (to listen for clicks) and for the ul (to select the display property).

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuicon");
var menu = document.getElementById("navlink");


function menuclick() {
  if (menu.style.display == none) {
    menu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
}

menuButton.addEventListener("click", menuclick);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 40, 140), rgb(50, 50, 180));
  min-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black inset;
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#h1s {
  font-size: .6em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

header ul li {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px black inset;
}

header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: .6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

  <header>
    <h1> Cole Pratt <span id="h1s"> No.2968615 </span> </h1>
    <img src="images/menuicon.png" alt="menuicon" width="40" id="menuicon" />
    <ul id="navlink">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>

</div>
```

Comment: `if (menu.style.display == none){` you forgot to put `none` in quotes so js thinks its a variable

Comment: thanks Josh but I had it in quotes before and it still wouldn't work, can you spot anything else?

Comment: after some research it seems you have to check for empty. i dont know why maybe someone can explain why `if (menu.style.display == ""){`

Comment: or rather both `if (menu.style.display == '' || menu.style.display == 'none')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setAttribute()` to do the work for you. and you forget to put `'none'` in single quotes.

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuicon");
var menu = document.getElementById("navlink");


function menuclick() {
  if (menu.style.display === 'none') {
    menu.setAttribute("style", "display:block");
  } else {
    menu.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
  }
}

menuButton.addEventListener("click", menuclick);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a `css class` to show/hide the menu items instead of using `inline styles`. See [Element.classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```js
var menuButton = document.getElementById("menuicon");
var menu = document.getElementById("navlink");


function menuclick() {
  menu.classList.toggle("active");
}

menuButton.addEventListener("click", menuclick);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(rgb(40, 40, 140), rgb(50, 50, 180));
  min-height: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black inset;
}

header h1 {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

#h1s {
  font-size: .6em;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
}

header ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

header ul.active {
  display: block;
}

header ul li {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px black inset;
}

header ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: .6em;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

  <header>
    <h1> Cole Pratt <span id="h1s"> No.2968615 </span> </h1>
    <img src="images/menuicon.png" alt="menuicon" width="40" id="menuicon" />
    <ul id="navlink">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>

</div>
```